# Why should developer care whether ios device was jailbroken

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, jailbreak

According to statistics I've found here [jailbreak-statistics-2013](http://www.businessinsider.com/jailbreak-statistics-2013-3) only 5% of devices are jailbroken. So why do iOS developers care about detecting jailbreaks?

People who jailbreak weren't going to pay anyway, but can generate rather good word of mouth, right?

Comment: I am not sure that's the best question for SO, since it's more general questions about business, security concerns and so on rather a specific question about a code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an enterprise developer I have a different set of challenges to safeguard with jailbroken devices such as sensitive data or passwords that should not be stored on the device or baked into code.

Regarding your comment about jailbreakers not "paying" for an app that's usually a fringe situation amongst that 5% that even try to take advantage of cracking an app. Most jailbreakers, including myself, do so for added functionality Apple doesn't provide out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

I think nobody develops thinking in JailBroken devices, honestly.

I don't care, and never knew anybody who did.

Answer (score 1):

A practical concern (besides trying to discourage theft) is that there are additional support costs when people with jailbroken devices submit bug reports or ask for help. A jailbroken device can have problems that don't happen with a stock device, and these problems can be very hard to track down when the device configuration is unknown.